# Выделение памяти типа auto

Tags: c++

Почему данная строка не вызывает у разработчиков стандарта казуса?

```
auto p = new auto(42);
```

Comment: @Abyx слишком не строготипизировано уже. Всё, что не запрещено - можно делать. Я бы не хотел такое увидить в коде - а вы?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Есть четыре вида длительности хранения памяти под объект (storage duration), и соответственно четыре способа создать объект:

- статическая, `static T variable(expression)`,
- потока, `thread_local T variable(expression)`,
- автоматическая, `T variable(expression)`,
- динамическая, `new T(expression)`.

Было бы странно, если бы вывод типов работал бы только для первых трех способов, но не работал бы для динамически выделяемой памяти.

Answer (score 13):

Когда используется спецификатор типа `auto`, то реальный тип выводится на основе типа инициализатора.

В этом выражении

```
new auto(42)
```

тип создаваемого динамически объекта определяется, исходя из типа выражения, используемого в качестве инициализатора объекта.

В данном случае это целочисленный литерал `42` , имеющий тип `int`. Поэтому создается объект этого типа в динамической памяти и инициализируется значением `42`.

Сам оператор возвращает указатель на созданный объект, то есть в приложении к данному примеру возвращается указатель `int *`

Поэтому в исходном предложении

```
auto p = new auto(42);
```

тип переменной `p` в свою очередь определяется из типа инициализатора в правой части от знака `=`, который, как я указал выше, имеет тип `int *`.

То есть в этом предложении создается два объекта, один - это безымянный объект в динамической памяти, а второй - это указатель, возможно, в автоматической или статической области памяти, и тип каждого из этих объектов определяется на основе соответствующего типа выражения, используемого в качестве инициализатора.

Вообще-то не следует злоупотреблять спецификатором `auto`, так как порой это может вызывать затруднения у читающего код, чтобы определить, какой реальный тип компилятор выведет для переменной со спецификатором `auto`.

Рассмотрите следующий, казалось бы, очень простой пример,

```
unsigned int x = 0;
long y = 0;

auto p = new auto( x + y );
```

Не каждый сможет правильно ответить, какой будет тип у указателя `p`, так как помимо всего прочего, правильный ответ зависит в том числе от используемой платформы.

Вот вам еще в копилку подобная на первый взгляд странная конструкция на этот раз касающаяся оператора преобразования, о которой можете почитать [здесь](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000073-000-0-0-1418985008)

Сейчас в стандарте C++ появилось много конструкций, которые интуитивно непонятны.

Я приведу пример одной из таких конструкций

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
decltype( auto ) c = ( a );
```

Обратите внимание на объявление переменной `c` и заключение в круглые скобки выражения `( a )`. Оказывается, это не совсем одно и то же, что объявление

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
decltype( auto ) c = a;
```

где выражение `a` не заключено в круглые скобки. Это предложение не будет компилироваться, в то время как предыдущее предложение с инициализатором в круглых скобках успешно скомпилируется.:)

Answer (score 3):

Это тоже самое, что `int* i = new int(42);`

Comment: `int*`. Справа - указатель.

Comment: @kff затупил, поправил